# 3NF Decomposition and NP-Completeness

Tags: database-design, normalization, design-pattern

I have a question about the computational complexity of the algorithm that allows us to decompose a schema into 3NF.

My book says that the decisional problem of telling if a schema complies with the 3NF is NP-Complete.
An NP problem is a decisional problem that can be solved in a polynomial time by a non-deterministic algorithm and verified in a polynomial time by a deterministic algorithm.
An NP-Complete problem is a problem that is as hard to solve as the SAT problem.

So, if I've understood correctly, if somebody gives me a schema and tells me wheater or not it is in 3NF I can verify it in polynomial time with a deterministic algorithm. But if somebody gives me the actual problem and not the decisional one by asking me: "Find a 3NF decomposition of my schema" I wouldn't be able to find a polynomial solution with a deterministic algorithm.

I would be glad if somebody could tell me if there are any mistakes in my understanding.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You understood it the other way around. The decision problem to the "is a schema in Third Normal Form?" question is NP-Complete, but given a schema you can find a Third Normal Form decomposition in polynomial time (it's not NP-Complete).

How is this so? The first time I heard this I said: "well, couldn't you prove that a schema is in 3NF in polynomial time by trying to decompose it and checking if there were no changes to the schema?". The problem is that you could decompose a 3NF schema even if it's in 3NF following the polynomial algorithm. So, the most common way to know if a relation is in 3NF is by finding all its candidate keys, but this is an NP-Complete problem by itself so there is no "easy" way to know if a schema is in 3NF